# Left outer join is not working on column with repeated id

Tags: mysql, sql

This is **table1**:

[image]

This is **table2**:

[image]

I wanted to see this result:

[image]

I wrote this query:

```
select title, value 
from table1 
left outer join table2 
    on table1.id = table2.id 
where category="good"
```

But it gives me this result:

[image]

So, what query should I use to get result with title c coming with ""? (empty string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the predicate on `table2.category` to the `ON` clause, rather than the `WHERE` clause.

(In the WHERE clause, that negates the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN operation, since any rows from table1 with no matching row from table2 would have values of NULL for the table2 columns. Checking for a non-null value excludes all the "unmatched" rows, rendering the `LEFT JOIN` equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`.

One way to return the specified resultset:

```
SELECT t.title
     , s.value
  FROM table1 t
  LEFT
  JOIN table2 s 
    ON s.id = t.id 
   AND s.category = "good"
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select title, value
from table1 
left outer join table2
on table1.id = table2.id and category="good"
```

Ann the `and category="good"` to the `on` clause. Not to the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a `left outer join`, you need to put conditions on the *second* table in the `on` clause.  If you put the condition in the `where` clause, then it will normally fail, because non-matching rows will have `NULL` values.

Conditions on the first table should go in the `where` clause.  So try this:

```
select title, value
from table1 left outer join
     table2
      on table1.id = table2.id and category = 'good';
```